# static transformer question

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to build a map using slam. I am using Arduino due and Ros indigo, I am capable of  building map with few error
I have this line in my launch file:

```
node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_kinect_broadcaster" args="-0.17 0.04 0.1975 0 0 0 \/base_link \/camera_link 100" />
```

I need to know if this line is necessary and what the parameter after the arg=   mean and how to tune them.
this is my main question.

I hope any one can replay with good answer I just need explanation and how to tune the parameter and what exactly this parameter mean.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253178/static-transformer-question/) by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-28**:
Also: not sure whether you added them for the forum, but remove the backslashes (`\`), they're not needed (nor valid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting [tf - ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher),

> static_transform_publisher x y z yaw
> pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id
> period_in_ms
>
> Publish a static coordinate transform
> to tf using an x/y/z offset in meters
> and yaw/pitch/roll in radians. (yaw is
> rotation about Z, pitch is rotation
> about Y, and roll is rotation about
> X). The period, in milliseconds,
> specifies how often to send a
> transform. 100ms (10hz) is a good
> value.

> static_transform_publisher x y
> z qx qy qz qw frame_id child_frame_id
> period_in_ms
>
> Publish a static coordinate transform
> to tf using an x/y/z offset in meters
> and quaternion. The period, in
> milliseconds, specifies how often to
> send a transform. 100ms (10hz) is a
> good value.

To answer your question : The coordinate systems of your camera and base link are different. Each camera image needs to be transformed into the global coordinate system. This transformation happens via the base_link frame. If you run

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

you will see the frames in your system.

To set the arg values properly, identify your base_link coordinate system origin and the camera coordinate system origin, measure the transformation and rotation between the two systems and update x,y,z, roll, pitch, yaw accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) with karma: 849 on 2017-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ghaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/26984/ghaith/) on 2017-01-28**:
you mean that I need to identify the origin of the camera related to the base link or related to the ground and is x mean here the desired position on x related to the object or mean something else.i am sry if my question is stupid but just to clear thing for me. thanks for answer,

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2017-01-28**:
You need to identify the origin of the camera wrt to the base_link.
So (x,y,z) is the origin of the camera's coordinate system in base_link coordinate system.
Eg: If (0,0,0) in camera's coordinate system is (10,-2,5.5) in the base_link coordinate system, then (x,y,z) is (10,-2,5.5). Same with r,p,y